# Couch Client throwing Runtime exception Could not determine if _bulk_get endpoint is supported

Tags: android, couchdb, cloudant

I am running an android application where cloudant replicates couch db in android. The application works on PDA. But its failing in Android Tablet with the following error.

> Replication Error. java.lang.RunTime Exception: Could not determine if
> the _bulk_get endpoint is supported. Caused by Couch Exception: error:
> Unknown error, reason: Unknown reason, statusCode: -1,

Answer (score 3):

The `_bulk_get` check is part of determining whether to use batches instead of individual fetches so it is pretty much the first thing that happens in the replication. If the request completed it would have a real status code, the `-1` suggests it didn't complete so maybe some kind of `IOException` like a connection timeout or an unresolvable host or similar problem.

IIRC there is usually another exception cause in the stack trace that will tell you what went wrong. Without that or some more logs I don't think there is an answer.